# How to order list of files by file name with number?

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting

I have a bunch of files in a directory that I am trying to get based off their type. Once I have them I would like to order them by file name (there is a number in them and I would like to order them that way)

My files returned are:

```
file-1.txt
file-2.txt
...
file-10.txt
file-11.txt
...
file-20.txt
```

But the order I get them in looks something more closely to this:

```
file-1.txt
file-10.txt
file-11.txt
...
file-2.txt
file-20.txt
```

Right now I am using `Directory.GetFiles()` and attempting to using the `linq OrderBy` property. However, I am failing pretty badly with what I would need to do to order my list of files like the first list above.

`Directory.GetFiles()` seems to be returning a list of strings so I am unable to get the list of file properties such as `filename` or `name`.

Here is my code currently:

```
documentPages = Directory.GetFiles(documentPath, "*.txt").OrderBy(Function(p) p).ToList()
```

Would anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I guess your comparison function would have to test if both filenames have a numeric part before the first (?) dot, and if so compare the prefixes before the numbers: if they're the same (case insensitively?) then parse and order by the numbers. In all other cases use the normal string ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the `file` and `.txt` parts are mutable, and just here as placeholders for file names and types that can vary.

I don't use regular expressions very often, so this may need some work yet, but it's definitely the direction you need to go:

```
Dim exp As String = "-([0-9]+)[.][^.]*$"
documentPages = Directory.GetFiles(documentPath, "*.txt").OrderBy(Function(p) Integer.Parse(Regex.Matches(p, exp)(0).Groups(1).Value)).ToList()
```

---

Looking again, I see I missed that you are filtering by `*.txt` files, which can help us narrow the expression:

```
Dim exp As String = "-([0-9]+)[.]txt$"
```

Another possible improvement brought by the other answer that includes test data is to allow for whitespace between the `-` and numerals:

```
Dim exp As String = "-[ ]*([0-9]+)[.]txt$"
```

---

It's further worth noting that the above *will* fail if there are text files that don't follow the pattern. We can account for that if needed:

```
Dim exp As String = "-[ ]*([0-9]+)[.][^.]*$"
Dim docs = Directory.GetFiles(documentPath, "*.txt")
documentPages = docs.OrderBy(
     Function(p) 
            Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(p, exp)
            If matches.Count = 0 OrElse matches(0).Groups.Count < 2 Then Return 0
            Return Integer.Parse(matches(0).Groups(1).Value)
     End Function).ToList()
```

You could also use `Integer.MaxValue` as your default option, depending on whether you want those to appear at the beginning or end of the list.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am falling a little short of seeing what you are doing in the OrderBy function. I tried using your code to see what was going to happen and i am getting an error. `Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As System.Func(Of String, TKey)) As System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of String)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error`. Could you explain what you were expecting to happen better?

Comment: Should be a little better now. As I said: I don't use these very often, and I typed this stuff into the reply window without using visual studio at all.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still a little confused as to the logic behind this, but your answer did solve my problem as close to my current code as possible. Instead of using your regex I used this instead `(?<=page-)\d+(?!.*/)`

Comment: Joel, out of curiousity, has you ever done reliable enough tests with different Regex expressions to get a feeling about the associated performance lacks? I don't use Regex too much but know that these approaches tend to perform quite badly in comparison with equivalent ones (like Split or Replace or similar). What I proposed performs 3 Splits what is not ideal, but even though shouldn't be notably faster than yours?

Comment: This is weird... I have tested this approach (with the two input sets of my answer, which are the same than the ones provided by the OP + invalid file names) and it crashes. Apparently it tries to parse "-1.txt" into an Integer (what I hope that everyone here knows that is impossible). I don't know much about Regex, but this seems to be wrong (I tested the last approach, the one working with all the formats). Now it is still more difficult to me to understand your behaviour, @scapegoat17; not appraising those trying to help you is one thing; but appraising what is wrong?!

Comment: And it keeps getting more weird... the original approach (the only meant to work with this specific format) is crashing too?! (in the first item "file-1.txt", too)?! As said, I am not an expert in Regex and perhaps I am missing something (but also potential readers); could you please, Joel (or scapegoat17 who sees correctness where I cannot), clarify this issue and explain me why I am not able to execute your code (I adapted it to List(of String))?

Comment: Finally had a chance to put this through visual studio and clean up my syntax. As for performance: Regex performance depends on how you use them. Regex are turned into state machines, and state machines can perform quite well.

Comment: @varocarbas - I really think that you need to relax a little bit lol. As I specified in my comment, i liked the approach that Joel was using mainly because I had already had my code closely set up the same way. I also noted in the comments that i used a different set of regex and this code works perfectly for me. I was just looking for someone to help me. I wasn't looking to start a long winded debate. I can show you a working example of Joel's code with the correct regex if you really are going to lose sleep over it tonight.. my goodness...

Comment: Joel recognise that it is a bit weird that the OP selected (and upvoted) the only answer not working; ignoring the other two ones. Regarding performance, I will make a quick comparison between hour approaches after you fisnish the corrections.

Comment: @scapegoat17 You can call it as you wish. But I will tell you what I saw (in an as relax way as I can): you got 3 answers; you ignored completely two of the answers/answerers (not saying thanks, hi, nothing); the only answer you upvoted and selected as the right one was wrong (the two versions in this post triggered errors). I don't know... perhaps I am a bit radical, but all this seems kind of bad to me. Now someone downvoted me (-> an answer delivering a 100% accuracy and, most likely, being the fastest one here = extremely fair, logical and motivated), it was you?

Comment: (1) @varocarbas - i dont know what to tell you about the down vote. Someone down voted me for asking a clear and descriptive question on SO, but again that is no huge deal to me. As for the 3 answers I got, I asked a question and went to grab lunch. Came back read through the 3 of them, and thought personally that the split was a bit messy. Again, that is objective to me and would rather use regex. I am getting more familiar with it and feel more comfortable using that. It is my personal preference. So please just leave it at that... I am not saying that your answer is wrong, I am just saying

Comment: (2) @varocarbas - this was the one that i used. with edited regex that also documented. So again, i dont see the big deal here...

Comment: @scapegoat17 (you are not saying that my answer is wrong because it is not). There is no big deal just interest in transmitting the ideas clearly to future readers (= upvoted + accepted which is wrong is not good to anyone) and to know more about the people I deal with (you know... I am kind of tired of certain attitudes, there are lots of people in SO and that's why now I choose very carefully who I help). Do you prefer regex than split? Up to you. You don't consider that you should show some kind of appreciation/deference for people helping, again up to you. I only wanted to know. Thanks.

Comment: @varocarbas - am all for conveying what you believe, but creating your political standpoint on how SO should be run and spamming Joel's poor answer is not the place to do it. And then going through various points of my posted question complaining about why you were not voted as the answer is just ridiculous. I dont know you, or where you work, or who you work with. And to be honest i dont really care to know or hear about it. And if you were in such interest in transmitting ideas clearly, you would not have blown up someones answer thread for this childish behavior.

Comment: @varocarbas - Seriously, I am not trying to offend you. I just feel like you went about this in a really incorrect way. Obviously we use SO to learn more. To answer your question (which i think i already did saying "Again, that is objective to me and would rather use regex", but understand  it was lost in all the text) yes I think when used correctly, Regex can be a stronger approach in providing solutions in certain situations. But if you really are this worked up about  1 of the million questions posted in SO and you would like to stop talking to me, i suggest you stop talking in my thread.

Comment: Joel, just to let you know that I did confirm that your approach was notably slower than the other ones we proposed; even with very small input sets. If you use Regex a lot, perhaps you should do some serious analysis of its performance because I am starting to think that it does have a quite relevant impact (with respect to equivalent approaches, like Split, Replace or similar). Logically, I mean in simple-enough cases where it might be easily replaced.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you might be looking for a "NaturalSort" - the kind of display File Explorer uses to order filenames containing numerals.  For this you need a custom comparer:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Partial Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Shared Function StrCmpLogicalW(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Int32
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function NaturalStringCompare(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Int32
        Return StrCmpLogicalW(str1, str2)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class NaturalStringComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Return NativeMethods.NaturalStringCompare(x, y)
    End Function
End Class
```

Use it to sort the results you get:

```
Dim myComparer As New NaturalStringComparer

' OP post only shows the filename without path, so strip off path:
' (wont affect the result, just the display)
Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path_name_here).
                 Select(Function(s) Path.GetFileName(s)).ToList
Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", String.Join(", ", files))

' sort the list using the Natural Comparer:
files.Sort(myComparer)
Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", String.Join(", ", files))
```

Results (one-lined to save space):

> Before: file-1.txt, file-10.txt, file-11.txt, file-19.txt, file-2.txt, file-20.txt, file-3.txt, file-9.txt, file-99.txt
>   After: file-1.txt, file-2.txt, file-3.txt, file-9.txt, file-10.txt, file-11.txt, file-19.txt, file-20.txt, file-99.txt

One of the advantages of this is that it doesnt rely on a specific pattern or coding.  It is more all-purpose and will handle more than one set of numbers in the text:

> > Game of Thrones\4 - A Feast For Crows\1 - Prologue.mp3
> >     Game of Thrones\4 - A Feast For Crows\2 - The Prophet.mp3
> >     ...
> >     Game of Thrones\4 - A Feast For Crows\10 - Brienne II.mp3
> >     Game of Thrones\4 - A Feast For Crows\11 - Sansa.mp3

---

A `Natural String Sort` is so handy, is is something I personally dont mind polluting Intellisense with by creating an extension:

```
' List<string> version
<Extension>
Function ToNaturalSort(l As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
    l.Sort(New NaturalStringComparer())
    Return l
End Function

' array version
<Extension>
Function ToNaturalSort(a As String()) As String()
    Array.Sort(a, New NaturalStringComparer())
    Return a
End Function
```

Usage now is even easier:

```
Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(your_path).
              Select(Function(s) Path.GetFileName(s)).
              ToList.
              ToNaturalSort()

' or without the path stripping:
Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(your_path).ToList.ToNaturalSort()
```