# Sort a list of string that contains integer and names

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, VB and MVC 5.  I have a list of office addresses.  These addresses are strings.  While most of these addresses are integers, there are a handful of them that have an actual name.

My list should look like this:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, Conference Room B, Conference Room C, Storage Room A

The problem currently is that when I pull my list from the database the order is not what most people expect.  When I put this list in a drop down menu it looks like this:

> 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, Conference Room B, Conference Room C, Storage Room A

I've tried to sort my linq query based on the office address.  I've also called `.sort()` on my list after the query.  Both of these options have not changed the order of the output.

How can I order my list so that it looks like the first example?

Comment: You want a [Natural Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33786276/1070452)

Comment: Yes, I didnt link to the question because it deals with files and the accepted answer uses a method which will only work with that pattern.  Not everyone reads past the question or accepted answer.