# Custom comparer datagridview sort

Tags: c#, vb.net, sorting, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a datagridview with a bindingsource as datasource, and the bindingsource has a datatable as a datasource. Some columns are strings but I want them to be sorted in a specific way.

The grid sorts them as 1, 10, 10,0 44a, 6c.

But I want them to sorted: 1, 6c, 10, 44a, 100 as if i would take the numbers only from the values and sort them accordingly.

Is there a way I cand add a custom comparer when certain columns are being sorted? Any other soulutions would be ok if the grid, bindingsource, datatable schema is not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is there a way I can add a custom comparer`  Yes!

When the DGV is bound to a `DataSource`, you have to act on (sort) the source not the DGV itself. This rules out some options like using the `SortCompare` event. The method below uses a `DataView`.

First, I started with the [Natural String Sorter from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786276/1070452) and made a few changes:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Partial Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Shared Function StrCmpLogicalW(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Int32
    End Function

    Friend Shared Function NaturalStringCompare(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Int32
        Return StrCmpLogicalW(str1, str2)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class NaturalStringComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of String)
    Private mySortFlipper As Int32 = 1

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(sort As SortOrder)
        mySortFlipper = If(sort = SortOrder.Ascending, 1, -1)
    End Sub

   Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer _
            Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare

        ' convert DBNull to empty string
        Dim x1 = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(x), String.Empty, x)
        Dim y1 = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(y), String.Empty, y)

        Return (mySortFlipper * NativeMethods.NaturalStringCompare(x1, y1))
    End Function
End Class
```

That Comparer can be used in a variety ways as evidenced from the linked question.  It is typically used for things like a `List` of file names.  Since the sort target here is DB data, a couple of lines were added to `Compare` for when it encounters null data.  (The OP, mvaculisteanu, discovered it was slow when null values were passed).

This would also work, handled as a separate step other edge cases can be easily added:

```vb
Return (mySortFlipper * NativeMethods.NaturalStringCompare(If(x, ""), If(y,""))
```

I don't know how you are using the `BindingSource`, so I had to make some guesses on the configuration.  My test `DataTable` has 3 columns, #1 is set to programmatic to implement the comparer.  Form level object variables used (so you understand my configuration - hopefully it is similar):

```vb
Private dgvDV As DataView
Private dgvBS As BindingSource

' config:
dgvDV = New DataView(dgvDT)

dgvBS = New BindingSource()
dgvBS.DataMember = "myDT"
dgvBS.DataSource = dgvDT

dgv2.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
dgv2.Columns(1).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
dgv2.Columns(2).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
```

The magic, such as it is, happens in the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event:

```vb
Private SortO As SortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending
Private Sub dgv2_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object...etc

    ' the special column we want to sort:
    If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        ' create new DV
        dgvDV = DGVNaturalColumnSort("Text", SortO)

        ' reset the BindingSource:
        dgvBS.DataSource = dgvDV
        ' update glyph
        dgv2.Columns(1).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortO

        ' flip order for next time:
        SortO = If(SortO = SortOrder.Ascending, SortOrder.Descending, SortOrder.Ascending)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then, a helper function which implements the sort and create a new `DataView`:

```vb
Private Function DGVNaturalColumnSort(colName As String, sortt As SortOrder) As DataView
    Dim NComparer As New NaturalStringComparer(sortt)
    Dim tempDT = dgvDV.Table.AsEnumerable().
        OrderBy(Function(s) s.Field(Of String)(colName), NComparer).
        CopyToDataTable

    Return New DataView(tempDT)
End Function
```

Because you pass the name of the column, it should be easy to use when there are multiple such columns.  Results:

[image]

Sort None on top, then Sort Asc and Desc below

User changes to the column(s) such as the order and width are preserved.  This also **works just fine without** a `BindingSource`.  Just use your `DataView` as the `DataSource`:

```vb
  dgvBS.DataSource = dgvDV
```

Using a `DataTable` as the `DataSource` could be problematic and "heavier" since you would have to copy the table.  A `DataView` makes this quite simple.

---

I also found this [AlphaNumeric sorter for java](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java).  Being curious, I converted it to .NET to compare them.  It works well but not quite the same.  Given the same starting point, 25-35 of 1000 sequences will typically come out differently:

```vb
 PInvoke:  03, 03, 03s, 3A
Alphanum:  03, 3A...3RB, 03s, 3X
```

Its not totally wrong, the `03s` is in the right area and the results synch back up for awhile after that. It also treats leading dashes differently and is a bit slower than PInvoke.  It does handle Nothing values fine though.

Comment: Thank you, I tested your method and it works great. I have an observation and a question. O: If the column contains null values then the sorting is very slow so I replaced  `Return (mySortFlipper * NativeMethods.NaturalStringCompare(x, y))` with  `Return (mySortFlipper * NativeMethods.NaturalStringCompare(If(x,""), If(y,"")))` Q: I have read from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspx) that the `StrCmpLogicalW` function is available starting from Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. Is it always available or some one can disable it

Comment: Ah, interesting!  I did not think to test it with nulls - it usually would be used with lists and collections where you are dealing with empty strings at worst.  I'll check that.   The user cannot disable it though - it is part of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would I think you would have to have another column because the computer reads the first number then the second. Which is why when you have 10 it reads this before 6. (1 is lower than 6) One way around this which I have done in the past is to have leading Zeros. So in 1 hidden column you would have leading zeros Example: 000006, 000100, then the visible column for the user you would have your original data but the sort column would be your hidden one.

Comment: I should have mention that this method is curently used in my project and I find it to be a bit cumbersome. It works but it's not as elegant as Plutonix soulution.

Answer (score 0):

This looked rather simple at first, then really hard and tedious and finally turned out to be really simple after all.. Hooray for LINQ!

First write a function that converts your `string` column to numeric values:

```
int noLetters(string text)
{
    char c = text[text.Length - 1];
    if (c < '0' || c > '9') text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
    int n = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(text, out n);
    return n;
}
```

Note: The function only tests the last letter and chops off anything that isn't a digit. Please do check this for **your rules** and add **your exception handling**!

Now order the data with the new function into a `DataView` via an `EnumerableRowCollection`:

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> sortedQuery =
    from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
    orderby noLetters(row.Field<string>("yourColumnName"))
    select row ;

DataView sortedView = sortedQuery.AsDataView();
yourBindingSource.DataSource = sortedView ;
```

To trigger it via a click on the column header simply code the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event..

Of course you can add logic to switch between `orderby` and `orderbydescending`