# Sorting datagridview items 9,000 to 10,000

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I'm trying to sort a datagridview but from 9,000 to 10,000, something doesn't work. The 10,000 is placed before the 9,000. Here's my code and a screenshot of my program

[image]

```
 DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Comment: That is how strings sort. "9" has a higher value than "1000"; it is sorting by the ASCII value of the characters.  Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: So how do i fix it?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour].  You need to show some effort to fix your pwn problems and ask an actual question.  If the numeric portion is not available on its own, you need to isolate it or use a Natural Sort.

Comment: [**Natural Sort Comparer**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22517/Natural-Sort-Comparer).

Comment: [Windows has it a Natural Sorter built in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33786276)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Linq's OrderBy clause. It allows you to split the string and sort by the numbers.

```
Dim dList As List(Of Datagridviewrow) = datagridview1.Rows.Cast(of DataGridViewRow).ToList()
dList = dList.OrderBy(Function(q) Integer.Parse(q.Cells(0).Value.ToString().Split("-").Last)).ToList()
DataGridView1.DataSource = dList.Select(function(x) x.DataBoundItem).ToList()
```

Comment: Answer updated after testing. This works as long as all cells in row 0 contain a "-#" format, which @Simon Stifler has in his example.

Comment: I tried it. I get the idea. The only problem is that I catch that error : object reference not set to an instance of an object. I think this thing happen when a cell is either empty or nothing comes after the " - ". My last row is always empty (don't know why). Is there a way to make a list without the last row ?

Comment: @SimonStifler instead of the second line, use dList = dList.Where(function(p) p.Cells(0).Value IsNot nothing).OrderBy(Function(q) Integer.Parse(q.Cells(0).Value.ToString().Split("-").Last)).ToList()

Comment: Dude, you are amazing! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer has helped, please consider marking the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are [few ways for custom sorting in the `DataGridView` Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608)

Usually the easiest and most general is to handle the [`DataGridView.SortCompare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare) event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SortCompare(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SortCompare
    If e.Column.Index <> 0 Then Return                            ' custom sort only for the first column
    e.SortResult = Len(e.CellValue1).CompareTo(Len(e.CellValue2)) ' compare by string length
    e.Handled = e.SortResult <> 0                                 ' to use the default comparison if same length
End Sub
```

---

Another option is to pass `IComparer` to the [`DataGridView.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs) method ([`.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198) needs .NET 4.5):

```
DataGridView1.Sort(Comparer(Of DataGridViewRow).Create(
                   Function(r1, r2)
                       Dim o1 = r1.Cells(0).Value, o2 = r2.Cells(0).Value
                       Dim i = Len(o1).CompareTo(Len(o2))
                       If i = 0 Then i = o1.ToString.CompareTo(o2)
                       Return i
                   End Function))
```